# Ошибка в java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry

Tags: java

Почему не работает? Постоянно вылезает ошибка:

```
at java.util.HashMap$HashIterator.nextEntry(Unknown Source)
at java.util.HashMap$KeyIterator.next(Unknown Source)
```

Вот сам код:

```
HashMap<Age, Integer> mapFromAgeToValues = new HashMap<Age, Integer>();
    mapFromAgeToValues.put(Age.AGE1, 1);
    mapFromAgeToValues.put(Age.AGE2, 11);
    mapFromAgeToValues.put(Age.AGE3, 111);
    mapFromAgeToValues.put(Age.AGE4, 1333);

    HashSet<Age> example = new HashSet<Age>();
    example.add(Age.AGE2);

    Integer r = 0;

    Iterator it = example.iterator();
    while ( it.hasNext() ){
        if ( mapFromAgeToValues.containsKey(it.next()) ){
            r += mapFromAgeToValues.get(it.next());
        }
    }
    out.println(r);
```

Age - Это просто энум

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что неправильно делать так

```
  if ( mapFromAgeToValues.containsKey(it.next()) ){
            r += mapFromAgeToValues.get(it.next());
        }
```

первым it.next() вы уже переходите к следующему элементу
попробуйте как то так

```
Age currentAge = it.next();
if ( mapFromAgeToValues.containsKey(currentAge) ){
     r += mapFromAgeToValues.get(currentAge);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, дружище!
Ночка на дворе, вот мозг уже и не соображает)
+ тебе в карму)